# XJC Plugin and access to XSOM parser

Tags: java, plugins, xjc

I need to access Plugins XSOM parser to invoke xSOMParser.setAnnotationParser(...) from XJC plugin before parsing. The problem is I have results of parsing, but not parser itself. I need to use ClassOutline.getSchemaComponent().getAnnotation().

<del>I know that there are binding customizations via plugin's  getCustomizationURIs() and getCustomizationURIs(...) which use appinfo -> custom annotation or external binding file. However, I have a lot of problems with them([XJC Plugin customizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338697/xjc-plugin-customizations)) and I wouldn't like to see if an alternative approach with AnnotationParser is possible.</del>

Answer (score 0):

From the XJC Plugin [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc/2.1.8/com/sun/tools/xjc/Plugin.java):

> Add-on that works on the generated source code. This add-on will be
>   called after the default bean generation has finished.

So my guess is that influencing the parser from an XJC Plugin is not possible. I think the right way to go would be writing a [JAXB2 Plugin](https://jaxb.java.net/plugin.html).

From the JAXB2 Page:

> What can a plugin do?
>
> A JAXB RI plugin participates in the code generation from a schema. It
>   can define its own customizations that users can use to control it, it
>   can access the code that the JAXB RI generates, and it can generate
>   additional classes/methods/fields/annotations/comments.
>
> A plugin can also choose to take over the XJC's code generation
>   process completely.